# React object property setting broken

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I think I found a react bug?
I have 2 functions to show my modal, first I have a modal state like this:

```js
    state = {
        modal: {
            requestPopUp: {
                visible: false,
            },
        },
    };
```

and 2 functions to hide/show it

```js
// Helper Methods
    handleOpenModal = name => {
        const modal = { ...this.state.modal };
        modal[name].visible = true;
        this.setState({ modal });
    };

    handleCloseModal = name => {
        const modal = { ...this.state.modal };
        modal[name].visible = false;
        this.setState({ modal });
    };
```

`handleOpenModal` works fine, however, `handleCloseModal` does not, it runs but doesnt alter the state.

`modal[name].visible = false;` This line specifically does nothing, I logged (modal,name) after it and it stays true and not false, how can I fix this??

Edit: I call my functions here:
`<div className="card request p-3" onClick={() => this.handleOpenModal("requestPopUp")}>`
Which works fine

and here
`<Modal show={modal.requestPopUp.visible} onHide={() => this.handleCloseModal("requestPopUp")}>`
Which also calls the function properly but it's never set as false as per the function logic.

My react version is         "react": "^16.12.0"

Comment: You are mutating the state. Try replacing that line with: `modal[name] = { ...modal[name], visible: false }` or just `modal[name] = { visible: false }` since you don't have any other property in it

Comment: More context is needed. It’s unlikely you found a bug in React here, though.

Comment: name is "requestPopUp", here?

Comment: @adiga tried it, no good

Comment: @DaveNewton What kind of context? I'm calling both functions which are almost identical and only the true one sets as true (It's initially false in state) and the other one doesn't set it as false, not in the "local" scope modal and therefore not in the state.

Comment: @JikunL Yes that's right

Comment: @OmarHussein Then you need to check your assumptions. One issue is that you're directly mutating state, even though you set it back to the state right away. "Context" means things like explicitly show the data in the question, the explicit call you're making, etc.

Comment: @DaveNewton How else would i mutate that visible value?

Comment: @OmarHussein As shown in the answer (and most React state management tutorials).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to avoid mutating the object props directly e.g (`obj[prop] = value`) since its antI-pattern ... Use destructering as my example below:

On a different note, no need to write the code twice, you can reuse the same function, and pass an extra param to define if u wanna close/open:

```
handleModalClick = (name, visible) => {
 this.setState({
    modal: {
      ...this.state.modal,
      [name]: {...this.state.modal[name], visible }
    }
 })
}
```

Comment: can you share the code on JSFiddle? there must be something wrong elsewhere, since I tested this and it works

Comment: Also shouldnt it be `show={this.state.modal.requestPopUp.visible}` ?

Comment: I have modal destructured,  render() {
  const { loading, modal } = this.state;

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/8xy1L6hb/2/ Can't get jsfiddle to work properly  but this should have all the relevant code as an example

Comment: @OmarHussein It works here: https://jsfiddle.net/Sletheren/wcx2qayv/5/

Comment: @OmarHussein And here, using your original(-ish) code: https://jsfiddle.net/davelnewton/9dj2cgpw/9/